# Is there a way to abort build in jenkins without increamenting jenkins build number?

Tags: jenkins

I need to stop build if a returned value from a script is false, but I need to completely cancel the build so that jenkins build number won't increment

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is. It wouldn't make much sense. After all even if the build has failed, it still happened and should be explicitly counted.

You're clearly looking for a mechanism to increment your release number and don't want gaps in the sequence.

The solution I use is the [buildnumber](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/buildnumber.html) task from Apache ivy. It obtains the next number in the sequence based on what has already been published to my release repository. While you may not be using the same technology the principle is very sound.